# Combine this array with jQuery, confused

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jqplot

I have two simple array in JavaScript, i want use it on **[jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/examples/multipleBarColors.php)** and required format data like this:

```
[[[x1, sin(x1)], [x2, sin(x2)], ...]]
```

My array is:

```
$array_1 = [ "Meong", "Aumix" ];
$array_2 = [ 3, 2 ];
```

How to combine/merge it with final output like as shown below:

```
$output = [[['Meong', 3], ['Aumix', 2]]];
```

I try use standar jQuery merge and combine not working.
Please help.

Comment: So what all you have tried so far?

Comment: I try  var merge = $.merge( $.merge( [[]], first ), second ); not working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (or [`jQuery.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)) to iterate one of the arrays, and get the value from the 2nd array using the `index`:

```js
var $array_1 = [ "Meong", "Aumix" ];
var $array_2 = [ 3, 2 ];

var result = $array_1.map(function(item, index) {
  return [item, $array_2[index]];
});

console.log([result]);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `reduce` method.

```js
$array_1 = [ "Meong", "Aumix" ];
$array_2 = [ 3, 2 ];
let finalArray=$array_1.reduce(function(acc,elem,i){
  acc.push([elem,$array_2[i]]);
  return acc;
},[]);
console.log([finalArray]);
```

Comment: Got to say i like the #map better then reduce, map is mor for getting back a new modified a array where as reduce is more for operation like get the sum of all items

Comment: @Endless, not everytime, `reduce` is used also for creating `arrays` and `objects`.